# Adding a responsive footer to a Squarespace page that works across device types

Tags: html, css, footer, squarespace

I've been working on a Squarespace site and a lot of their templates do not have footers. I require a copyright and privacy policy link so this a footer is required.

Luckily one can adapt the base templates with the 'code injection' tool and I have been using the code provided by [this great answer][1] however when resizing to tablet or mobile screen sizes, the footer ends up in the middle of the page.

I've tried adapting the code to use

`position: fixed; 
 bottom: 0:`

as suggested by some other answers but the problem persists and still unable to fix the footer to the bottom of the page, regardless of screen size.

**EDITED**
The code below works perfectly and maintains a footer at the bottom of the page across all the views on Squarespace (phone, tablet, web):

```
<style>
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  overflow: auto;
}

#coverFooter {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* top: 100%;  */
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  /* Use this for right aligned text instead.
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 60px;
        padding-left: 60px;
        */
}

#coverPP {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#coverCR {
  margin-left: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

<div class="box">
  <div id="coverFooter">
    <span id="coverCR">&copy; 2017 Your Business</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try below css part

As your need - **[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lokeshg27/tp53tv82/5/)**

Add css

```
 .box {
   width:100%;
   height:calc(100vh - 60px);
   background:tomato;
   overflow:auto;
 }
```

Remove part

```
#coverFooter {
   /* top: 100%;  */ 
   bottom:0px; /* Add this */
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  background: tomato;
  overflow: auto;
}

#coverFooter {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  /* top: 100%;  */
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  /* Use this for right aligned text instead.
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 60px;
        padding-left: 60px;
        */
}

#coverPP {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#coverCR {
  margin-left: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit repellat totam recusandae pariatur nemo molestias accusantium doloribus. Praesentium distinctio dicta assumenda, consequuntur tempora eos eveniet ex magnam nobis, aperiam hic?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit repellat totam recusandae pariatur nemo molestias accusantium doloribus. Praesentium distinctio dicta assumenda, consequuntur tempora eos eveniet ex magnam nobis, aperiam hic?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit repellat totam recusandae pariatur nemo molestias accusantium doloribus. Praesentium distinctio dicta assumenda, consequuntur tempora eos eveniet ex magnam nobis, aperiam hic?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit repellat totam recusandae pariatur nemo molestias accusantium doloribus. Praesentium distinctio dicta assumenda, consequuntur tempora eos eveniet ex magnam nobis, aperiam hic?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit repellat totam recusandae pariatur nemo molestias accusantium doloribus. Praesentium distinctio dicta assumenda, consequuntur tempora eos eveniet ex magnam nobis, aperiam hic?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit repellat totam recusandae pariatur nemo molestias accusantium doloribus. Praesentium distinctio dicta assumenda, consequuntur tempora eos eveniet ex magnam nobis, aperiam hic?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit repellat totam recusandae pariatur nemo molestias accusantium doloribus. Praesentium distinctio dicta assumenda, consequuntur tempora eos eveniet ex magnam nobis, aperiam hic?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit repellat totam recusandae pariatur nemo molestias accusantium doloribus. Praesentium distinctio dicta assumenda, consequuntur tempora eos eveniet ex magnam nobis, aperiam hic?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit repellat totam recusandae pariatur nemo molestias accusantium doloribus. Praesentium distinctio dicta assumenda, consequuntur tempora eos eveniet ex magnam nobis, aperiam hic?
  </p>
  <div id="coverFooter">
    <a id="coverPP" href="/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a> <span id="coverCR">&copy; 2016 Your Company, LLC</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I am not looking for the footer to be fixed on the bottom of a screen, I'm looking for it to be fixed to the bottom of the page so that it can be scrolled down to. 

Also, I don't need to add any text above it. The content on the page - above the footer - is handled in the form of Squarespace components.

Comment: Then change position fixed to relative and box height is 100vh